# How to display changed strings to the user

Tags: java

I'm currently in college and starting learning java. It's been one of those weeks so I'm a bit behind and stuck on my last problem was hoping maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TextMsgExpander {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       String userInput = "";
       String changeAbr = "";


       System.out.println("Enter text: ");
       userInput = scnr.nextLine();
       System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

       changeAbr = userInput;

       changeAbr = changeAbr.replace("BFF", "best friend forever");
       changeAbr = changeAbr.replace("IDK", "I don't know");
       changeAbr = changeAbr.replace("JK", "just kidding");
       changeAbr = changeAbr.replace("TTYL", "talk to you later");

       return;
```

Basically, what I still need to figure out is how to print.ln of what actually changed to the user. (ex: Replaced "IDK" with "I don't know".) I'm completely dumbfounded at how to do this. I've tried quite a few different ways of doing so to no avail so far. Looking throughout the book and I'm not coming up with a single answer and I can't seem to figure out how to word it to find something similar on Google.

Comment: Have you tried using an if block to check the string for the condition yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to print what you're replacing as you replace it, the easiest thing to do is to put the searches and replacements into a `Map`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("BFF", "best friend forever");
// etc.
```

Then you can iterate the entries in this map:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String search = entry.getKey();
  String replacement = entry.getValue();

  // ...
}
```

In the `// ...` in this loop:

- Check if `changeAbr` contains the search string;
- If it does, print a message, and replace the search with the replacement.

I'm leaving out the specific code because you should work out how to do it - it'll be a good learning experience :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind long answers for this... lol

If the text has been replaced, obviously, it exists in the string. So you can just simply do the inverse process, if it exists in the string, then replace, and additionally, warn the user.

### Not using regex `</3`:

E.g.:

```
   changeAbr = userInput;
   if (changeAbr.contains("BFF")){
       changeAbr = changeAbr.replace("BFF", "best friend forever");
       System.out.println("Detected the word BFF! (Replaced)");
   }
```

Let's use some functions here, so it won't get soo long:

```
 public static String rpl(String txt, String toReplace, String replacement){
        if (txt.contains(toReplace)){
            System.out.println("Detected the word " + toReplace + "! (Replaced)");
            return txt.replace(toReplace, replacement);
        }
     return txt;
 }
```

And then use it to replace the text **and** warn the user:

```
    changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "BFF", "best friend forever");
    changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "IDK", "I don't know");
    changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "JK", "just kidding");
    changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "TTYL", "talk to you later");
    System.out.println(changeAbr);
```

**FULL CODE**

```
public static String rpl(String txt, String toReplace, String replacement){
        if (txt.contains(toReplace)){
            System.out.println("Detected the word " + toReplace + "! (Replaced)");
            return txt.replace(toReplace, replacement);
        }
     return txt;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   String userInput = "";
   String changeAbr = "";


   System.out.println("Enter text: ");
   userInput = scnr.nextLine();
   System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

   changeAbr = userInput;

   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "BFF", "best friend forever");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "IDK", "I don't know");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "JK", "just kidding");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "TTYL", "talk to you later");
}
```

---

### Using Regex! `<3`:

Now additionally, if you want to show the user how many times it was replaced, you could use regex (which is not going to be useless here, since we can also use boundaries `\b`, in case the user types a word containing the abbreviations, we can also show the text position, and even ignore caps with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` if needed). Here is the function for this:

```
public static String rpl(String txt, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile("\\b"+toReplace+"\\b");
    Matcher matcher = a.matcher(txt);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(
                "Detected the word " + toReplace + " at position " + matcher.start() + " to " + matcher.end() + " (Replaced)");
        txt = matcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
        matcher = a.matcher(txt);
    }
    return txt;
}
```

**FULL CODE**

```
public static String rpl(String txt, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile("\\b"+toReplace+"\\b");
    Matcher matcher = a.matcher(txt);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(
                "Detected the word " + toReplace + " at position " + matcher.start() + " to " + matcher.end() + " (Replaced)");
        txt = matcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
        matcher = a.matcher(txt);
    }
    return txt;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   String userInput = "";
   String changeAbr = "";


   System.out.println("Enter text: ");
   userInput = scnr.nextLine();
   System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

   changeAbr = userInput;

   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "BFF", "best friend forever");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "IDK", "I don't know");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "JK", "just kidding");
   changeAbr = rpl(changeAbr, "TTYL", "talk to you later");
   System.out.println(changeAbr);
}
```

#### Output:

> Enter text: 
>   **> hey BFF! IDK what to type but you're my BFF :D (from JKing)**
>   You entered: *hey BFF! IDK what to type but you're my BFF :D (from JKing)*
>   Detected the word **BFF** at position **4** to **7** (Replaced)
>   Detected the word **BFF** at position **56** to **59** (Replaced)
>   Detected the word **IDK** at position **25** to **28** (Replaced)
>
> hey best friend forever! I don't know what to type but you're my best friend forever :D (from JKing)

Notes:

- `JKing` wasn't replaced to `just kiddinging`, that's because of the word boundaries.
- Text positions (the bold numbers) are relative. They'll always show the position of the text **AFTER** the previous replacement.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
System.out.println(changeAbr);
```

This will print out the value of the `changeAbr` variable.

If you need to print each change, you will need to use another Scanner that
scans each word in the input line, like this:

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(userInput);
String outLine = "";
while (line.hasNext()) {
    String word = line.next();
    switch (word) {
        case "BFF":
            System.out.println("Replaced BFF with 'Best Friend Forever'");
            outLine += "best friend forever";
            break;
        ...
        default:
            outLine += word;
            break;
     }
     outLine += " ";
}
```

One problem with this code is that it will not recognize words with punctuation immediately after them (e.g. `JK!`), but this can be fixed easily.

Comment: I was attempted to implement this into the code, but came up with two issues. One is the punctuation issue that you mentioned(about to look into the book to see if they mention it). Second that it only finds the first abbreviated text in the string to modify. This is the closest to what we're learning so figured it'd be the best to attempt to implement into the code.

Answer (score -1):

Use multiple if blocks

```
 If(string.contains(text)){
     System.out.println(abv + " changed 
     to " + convertedAbv);
 } if(second condition) etc...
```